# How to make cache directory writable

Tags: php, image

Forgive me for my simple question but how do you make it writable?

I read it it needs to be change to for example: for timthumbs or http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

"Make your imagecache directory is writable by the web server (usually chmod 775)"

So I just call the function or what?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's a bad idea to `chmod 755` directories without some serious forethought.  On your webserver, there will be a user that the web server software runs as, usually something like `www-data` or `apache`.  You can `chown -R apache /path/to/your/cache/dir` and that way PHP can write to that directory.

EDIT:  To clarify, these are commands you would run from a shell on your webserver, such as via SSH.  They are not PHP functions.  Your web host should have more information about how you can get shell access.

Answer (score 0):

chmod is a command line unix/linux command. You'd access it via an SSH console or you should be able to modify with whatever mechanism you're using to upload the files with (SSH, SFTP, FTP, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `chmod` command to change folder permissions

```
chmod 775 foldername
```

or if you are using FTP, you can use filezilla (right click on folder, and type 775 in the permissions)